# What is monkey's in this simple sentence clause?

Tags: verbs, clauses, subjects

If a clause is one subject, one verb; (SV.) and there is one clause in this sentence; then what part of speech is "monkeys"?  It seems to me it would be another subject.

> Mr. Potato Head eats monkeys.

subject

- "Mr. Potato Head"

verb

- "eats"

Comment: It's a noun, the direct object of *eats*.

Comment: @StoneyB But what differentiates it from the subject?  The fact that the subject comes first, or that it is a "direct object" of the verb (eats)?

Comment: It is the object primarily because of word position. Also, "Mr. Potato Head" is the only singular noun, so only it may be the subject of "eats" (which requires a singular subject, but can take a singular or plural object).

Comment: @leeand00 The subject performs the action of the verb, the object is affected by the action. In "Jack drives the car" Jack is doing the driving and the car is being driven. In "Mr Potato Head eats monkeys" Mr Potato Head is doing the eating and the monkeys are being eaten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **subject** is the person or thing (Mr. Potato Head) performing  the **action** (eats) and the **direct object** is the thing/person  that the action is directed towards (**receives the action = monkeys).**

To find the direct object refer to the verb and ask what or who.

e.g. Mr. Potato head **eats what?** **answer** = he eats monkeys= direct object.

Also, your whole sentence is a clause because a clause contains a subject and verb.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, "*Mr. Potato Head eats monkeys.*" contains *subject*, *verb*, *object*, in that order. This is typical of an English sentence in the active voice.

As also noted in comments, *Mr. Potato Head* is singular, which fits with the verb singuar conjugation of *eats*, whereas *monkeys* is plural. And in English you cannot write e.g. *Mr. Potato Head eat monkeys.*, where *monkeys* is the subject and *Mr. Potato Head* is the object, nor can you write *Monkeys eats Mr. Potato Head*, with the subject after the verb (compared with German where you may normally write *Mr. Potato Head isst Affen* but *could* also write *Affen isst Mr. Potato Head* since the grammar rules do allow that).